# Shapefile to raster conversion in R?

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, data-conversion, rasterizing

I have a shapefile downloaded from the worldwildlife.org for the terrestrial ecoregions of the world. The file can be loaded here: http://worldwildlife.org/publications/terrestrial-ecoregions-of-the-world.

It comes as a standard shape file and I would like to do two things with it. 
First: take the shapefile from my local directory and clip it to an extent of eastern North America  (ext=  extent (-95, -50, 24, 63))

```
# Read shapefile using package "maptools"
eco_shp <- readShapeLines("F:/01_2013/Ecoregions/Global/wwf_terr_ecos.shp", 
                          proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84")) 


# Set the desired extent for the final raster using package "raster" 
ext <- extent(-95, -50, 24, 63)
```

I am sure I have to use the rasterize function in the package "raster" but I am still not able to get it work correctly. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Do you need it to be rasterised? Would cliping the shapefile by a polygon suffice?

Comment: Mnel: I do need it to be rasterized into an .asc file to match up with my other environmental layers.

Comment: The first step of clipping by a shapfile would be helpful, then that new object could be rasterized and might be less intensive .

Comment: why not just overlay the polygon onto the SpatialGridDataFrame you wish to match it to, (use `overlay`)

Comment: Mnel: My model requires that my input dataframes all be in an asc format and have the same spatial extent. If I only wanted to visualize it the "overlay" would work. :)

Comment: The `overlay` function in R will extract the values at the grid points, you could then save as an ascii file.

Comment: Im sorry, I am new to working on GIS in R. Is the idea to make a empty raster with the desired extent then overlay the shapefile and extract the values to the points that way?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Have a look at the answer I just posted for an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are right to think that you should be using `raster` (rather than the `sp` raster Spatial classes) for spatial raster data.  You should also use `rgdal` (rather than `maptools`) for reading, writing, and otherwise manipulating spatial vector data.

This should get you started:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

## Read in the ecoregion shapefile (located in R's current working directory)
teow <- readOGR(dsn = "official_teow/official", layer = "wwf_terr_ecos")

## Set up a raster "template" to use in rasterize()
ext <-  extent (-95, -50, 24, 63)
xy <- abs(apply(as.matrix(bbox(ext)), 1, diff))
n <- 5
r <- raster(ext, ncol=xy[1]*n, nrow=xy[2]*n)

## Rasterize the shapefile
rr <-rasterize(teow, r)

## A couple of outputs
writeRaster(rr, "teow.asc")
plot(rr)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that. Note that in practice, you'll probably want to use one of your own raster layers as the template raster (`r` in `rasterize(teow, r)`), and may need to do a bit of fiddling to get the proj4strings matched up (although both **raster** and **rgdal** are really good about handling projection metadata.).

Comment: It should be noted that rasterize() appears to be impossibly unstable and inefficient with large datasets. I recently tried to rasterize a coverage of the city of Seattle at 6ft resolution (the output is a 14 MB GeoTIFF file, 8095 x 14819) and R spent about three hours running 7 threads before "finishing" with no output and no error message either. Using R to generate a blank GeoTIFF raster of the desired extent and resolution, and then running the rasterize operation via gdal (with some help from QGIS) took less than half an hour in a single thread.

Comment: @MilesErickson Indeed. For any but the smallest rasters, I tend to use a wrapper around `gdalUtils::gdal_rasterize`. For 1000-by-1000 rasters, I get a 6-fold speed-up, and for 2000-by-2000 rasters, I get a 12-fold speed-up (from 70 to 6 seconds).

Comment: Great tip! Wow, so rasterize() might have taken weeks or years to finish my 8000x15000 raster, had it been able to at all...

Comment: Hey @Josh you created variable `n` but did not use it? Did you mean `r <- raster(ext, ncol=xy[1]*n, nrow=xy[2]*n)`?

Comment: @BhargavRao I did indeed. Thanks! (Fixed it.)

Comment: Nice, @Josh Thanks. I have made a small edit to reflect the code formatting.

Comment: For a raster 79862 by 67313, gdal(python) takes about 100 seconds. The R raster package takes all day and usually crashes.  The difference is that gdal is a C application and is optimized...whereas the code for raster->rasterize is written in R and uses way too much memory.